# Service entrance wire

Tags: wiring

I have built a detached garage in front of my house. National Grid has spotted my meter on the front of my garage. I would like to run my new entrance wires from the meter about 60' underground to my existing 200 amp panel in my house. Is it legal if the wire is run in conduit? I live in New York State, and it will be inspected.
I would then come off the house panel to the garage's sub panel.
Thanks, Lew

Comment: This is very unclear. Your house has no power now, (perhaps bohth house and garage are new) or you have a house with power and you built a new garage in front of it? Please [edit] to clarify the details of what's going on here, really. Perhaps include some pictures of the setup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to have a main breaker at the meter.

Since I presume you'll want to power things in the garage, a great choice here is a "Ranch Panel" which provides a main breaker, an 8-space mini-panel, and then **thru lugs** to carry full power onward to the house.

Then you'll need to run 4-wire *feeder* to the house.   The feeder will be protected by the circuit breaker at the meter, so there'll be no special rules about routing.

The house will also need a main-breaker panel* however it doesn't need to be outdoors.  Neutral and ground must be separated at this panel.

The house also needs local ground rods unless it is attached to the garage by at least a breezeway.  The ground rods do a different job than the ground wire, one doesn't substitute for the other. *It's been tried*.

Yes, I know you don't want to do it that way.  If you want to do it the old way, move to a state that's on NEC 2005.  (a few counties in in IL, AZ, MO or MS).

---

* Technically, you need a *disconnect* near where the power enters the house, and it can be indoors. But 200A stand-alone disconnects are expensive, and the cheapest way to comply is simply to use a main-breaker panel.  So that's what *everybody* does.